# Android: How to implement pre-cached functionality with google map in my app?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application i need to  implement pre-cached functionality like native Google map application in android phone.I have map in my application already when i navigate from one point to another point it starts loading the map i want in my application i could store map if a particular city not whole world because it would be too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with Native MapView ([Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/maps-api-signup)). Take a look at [OSM](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) !

Comment: It's really not a comment, it is an answer. You can't cache Tiles with Native MapView...

Comment: ok great lets wait and see if anyone have any alternative of this. +1 to you.

Comment: You don't get it, the Terms of Services of Native Maps API don't let you do that... You have to use another Map Library... I suggest OSM.